# Keyboard shortcut for opening full editor for file being compared in svn

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

In Eclipse when I synchronize with the SVN repository for a Java file to see changes I can open up files in the compare view to see the changes I make. Quite often after reviewing the changes I want to open the full editor to make additional changes.

In Eclipse Oxygen I could click on the class name or a method declaration in my local changes and hit F3 and that would open up the full editor. I don't know if the behaviour was intended but it was useful. However after I have updated to Eclipse June 2019 the trick no longer works - nothing is opened and the class name just becomes selected instead.

I have checked the key bindings of F3 between the two versions and it is identical. Is there a way to add such a keyboard shortcut in Eclipse or is there already an existing one that I do not know about to do this? Alternatively is this an introduced bug and I should report it?

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click the package, file or project and found Compare with option. Under that menu, we have various options for comparing with SVN tags/branches or particular version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it does not answer the question. I have the compare view open but I want to exit the compare view for the file and open the normal editor for it. Your answer gives how to open the compare view which I don't have any problems with doing.